# if statement in SQL to calculate age

Tags: excel, oracle, join

I am very new at SQL and I have been working on my First Query. Now I need your help.
I have this report in Excel. I have formula in the AGE column N calculating the AGE.  I have been trying to create a SQL query to come up with the same answer.  So far I have figured out the columns that I need and pulled all the data to Match Excel.  Only thing is I don't know how and where to enter this IF statement so it will calculate the age when i run the query.

```
Work Order  Location    MISC    Status  Actual Finish   Finish Time Parent WO   Work Type   N   Reported Date   Reported Time   Site    Gen Age Sub Name    Substation Location                         
1234567899  4074        COMP    11/5/14 3:08:49 PM      CM      10/7/14 1:47:42 PM          29.05633102                                 
12348574987 2946        SCHED               CM      10/30/14    10:28:03 AM         188.5638542
```

AGE is a formula, pasted below:

```
=IF ((IF(Status<>"Comp",Today()-Reported date, actual finish-reported date))<0,0, IF(STATUS<>"COMP", TODAY()-REPORTED DATE, ACTUAL FINISH-REPORTED DATE))
```

SQL Writen Query

```
SELECT WO.WONUM,                                                                                        
  LOCOFFDESC.DESCRIPTION AS OFFICE,                                                                                     
  WO.STATUS,                                                                                        
  WO.LOCATION,                                                                                      
  CASE                                                                                      
    WHEN ((INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 2, 3)) = 0)                                                                                        
    THEN SUBSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, ((INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 1, 2) + 2)), LENGTH(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH))                                                                                      
    WHEN ((INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 2, 3)) IS NOT NULL)                                                                                        
    THEN SUBSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, ((INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 1, 2) + 2)), (INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 2, 3)) - (INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 1, 2) + 2))                                                                                      
  END AS "SUBSTATION CASE",                                                                                     
  WO.PARENT,                                                                                        
  WO.WORKTYPE,                                                                                      
  WO.REPORTEDBY,                                                                                        
  WO.REPORTDATE,                                                                                        
  WO.ACTFINISH,                                                                                     
  WO.SITEID                                                                                     
FROM LOCATIONS LOCOFF                                                                                       
RIGHT JOIN MAXPRD.WORKORDER WO                                                                                      
ON WO.LOCATION = LOCOFF.LOCATION                                                                                        
INNER JOIN MAXPRD.LOCANCESTOR LOCOFFANC                                                                                     
ON LOCOFFANC.LOCATION = LOCOFF.LOCATION                                                                                     
INNER JOIN MAXPRD.LOCATIONS LOCOFFDESC                                                                                      
ON LOCOFFANC.ANCESTOR = LOCOFFDESC.LOCATION                                                                                     
INNER JOIN MAXPRD.LOCHIERARCHY LOCOFFHIER                                                                                       
ON LOCOFFANC.ANCESTOR = LOCOFFHIER.LOCATION                                                                                     
WHERE LOCOFF.SITEID   = 'SUB'                                                                                       
AND LOCOFFHIER.PARENT = '2000'                                                                                      
GROUP BY WO.WONUM,                                                                                      
  LOCOFFDESC.DESCRIPTION,                                                                                       
  WO.STATUS,                                                                                        
  WO.LOCATION,                                                                                      
  LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH,                                                                                        
  LOCOFF.SITEID,                                                                                        
  LOCOFFHIER.PARENT,                                                                                        
  WO.PARENT,                                                                                        
  WO.WORKTYPE,                                                                                      
  WO.REPORTEDBY,                                                                                        
  WO.REPORTDATE,                                                                                        
  WO.ACTFINISH,                                                                                     
  WO.SITEID
```

Comment: Is this for Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL?  They're not the same thing.  Please remove the tag that does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

You place the calculation after the SELECT statement, before the FROM statement, so you have a column filled with calculated values, similar to excel.

We need to know what database system you are working with to get the exact syntax. Can you try after WO.SITEID,

```
SELECT WO.WONUM,
  LOCOFFDESC.DESCRIPTION AS OFFICE,
  WO.STATUS,
  WO.LOCATION,
  CASE
    WHEN ((INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 2, 3)) = 0)
    THEN SUBSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, ((INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 1, 2) + 2)), LENGTH(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH))
    WHEN ((INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 2, 3)) IS NOT NULL)
    THEN SUBSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, ((INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 1, 2) + 2)), (INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 2, 3)) - (INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 1, 2) + 2))
  END AS "SUBSTATION CASE",
  WO.PARENT,
  WO.WORKTYPE,
  WO.REPORTEDBY,
  WO.REPORTDATE,
  WO.ACTFINISH,
  WO.SITEID,
 (
CASE 
    WHEN (
        CASE WHEN WO.STATUS != 'Comp'
            THEN SYSDATE-WO.REPORTDATE
            ELSE WO.ACTFINISH-WO.REPORTDATE
        END) < 0
        THEN 0
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN STATUS != 'COMP'
                THEN SYSDATE-WO.REPORTDATE
                ELSE WO.ACTFINISH-WO.REPORTDATE
            END
END) as age
FROM LOCATIONS LOCOFF
RIGHT JOIN MAXPRD.WORKORDER WO
ON WO.LOCATION = LOCOFF.LOCATION
INNER JOIN MAXPRD.LOCANCESTOR LOCOFFANC
ON LOCOFFANC.LOCATION = LOCOFF.LOCATION
INNER JOIN MAXPRD.LOCATIONS LOCOFFDESC
ON LOCOFFANC.ANCESTOR = LOCOFFDESC.LOCATION
INNER JOIN MAXPRD.LOCHIERARCHY LOCOFFHIER
ON LOCOFFANC.ANCESTOR = LOCOFFHIER.LOCATION
WHERE LOCOFF.SITEID   = 'SUB'
AND LOCOFFHIER.PARENT = '2000'
GROUP BY WO.WONUM,
  LOCOFFDESC.DESCRIPTION,
  WO.STATUS,
  WO.LOCATION,
  LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH,
  LOCOFF.SITEID,
  LOCOFFHIER.PARENT,
  WO.PARENT,
  WO.WORKTYPE,
  WO.REPORTEDBY,
  WO.REPORTDATE,
  WO.ACTFINISH,
  WO.SITEID
```

Edited for MS SQL server. Edited AGAIN for Oracle :)

Comment: You can't use an IF statement in a query. If is used to control flow, to conditionally handle output you would use a case expression.

Comment: Glad you added your input and down voted me but you can  use IF in a query exactly like this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: Not in sql server you can't. This is tagged with mysql also, maybe you can do that in mysql.

Comment: You can, I pasted the link to mysql IF function document above.

Comment: Cool I don't know mysql and didn't notice the tag and I don't know mysql. Still not sure which DBMS the OP is using. >.<

Comment: I have to work with so many different syntaxes, they all blur into one for me :( I'm going to assume SQL server due to the excel stuff.

Comment: This was my first time on sit site and I wasn't sure what to tag.  I am writing this query in SQL Developer.

Comment: I have added the statement as you have written about and got following error: ORA-0090:invalid relational operator 00920.00000 - "invalid relational operator" *cause: *Action:  Error at Line 27 column:24

Comment: I've updated my answer to be specific to oracle try again please :)