# Create IF Statement in SQL developer to calculate AGE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this report in Excel running from Maximo. I have forumla in the AGE column N calculating the AGE.  I have been trying to create a SQL query to come up with the same answer.  So far I have figured out the columns that I need and pulled all the data to Match Excel.  Only thing is I don't know **how and where** to enter this IF statement so it will calculate the age when i run the query.

```
Work Order  Location    MISC    Status  Actual Finish   Finish Time Parent WO   Work Type   N   Reported Date   Reported Time   Site    Gen Age Sub Name    Substation Location
1234567899  4074        COMP    11/5/14 3:08:49 PM      CM      10/7/14 1:47:42 PM          29.05633102     
12348574987 2946        SCHED               CM      10/30/14    10:28:03 AM         188.5638542
```

AGE is a formula, pasted below:

```
=IF((IF(STATUS<>"COMP",TODAY()-REPORTED DATE,ACTUALFINISH-REPORTED DATE))<0,0,IF(STATUS<>'COMP", TODAY() - REPORTED DATE, ACTUAL FINISH - REPORTED DATE))
```

Here's is my current SQL Query:

```
SELECT WO.WONUM,
       LOCOFFDESC.DESCRIPTION AS OFFICE,
       WO.STATUS,
       WO.LOCATION,

       CASE

           WHEN ((INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 2, 3)) = 0)
           THEN SUBSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, ((INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 1, 2) + 2)), LENGTH(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH))

           WHEN ((INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 2, 3)) IS NOT NULL) 
           THEN SUBSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, ((INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 1, 2) + 2)), (INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 2, 3)) - (INSTR(LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH, '/', 1, 2) + 2))
       END AS "SUBSTATION CASE",

       WO.PARENT,
       WO.WORKTYPE,
       WO.REPORTEDBY,
       WO.REPORTDATE,
       WO.ACTFINISH,
       WO.SITEID

FROM LOCATIONS LOCOFF
RIGHT JOIN MAXPRD.WORKORDER WO ON WO.LOCATION = LOCOFF.LOCATION
INNER JOIN MAXPRD.LOCANCESTOR LOCOFFANC ON LOCOFFANC.LOCATION = LOCOFF.LOCATION
INNER JOIN MAXPRD.LOCATIONS LOCOFFDESC ON LOCOFFANC.ANCESTOR = LOCOFFDESC.LOCATION
INNER JOIN MAXPRD.LOCHIERARCHY LOCOFFHIER ON LOCOFFANC.ANCESTOR = LOCOFFHIER.LOCATION
WHERE LOCOFF.SITEID = 'SUB'
  AND LOCOFFHIER.PARENT = '2000'
GROUP BY WO.WONUM,
         LOCOFFDESC.DESCRIPTION,
         WO.STATUS,
         WO.LOCATION,
         LOCOFF.EXT_LOC_HIERARCHY_PATH,
         LOCOFF.SITEID,
         LOCOFFHIER.PARENT,
         WO.PARENT,
         WO.WORKTYPE,
         WO.REPORTEDBY,
         WO.REPORTDATE,
         WO.ACTFINISH,
         WO.SITEID
```

Comment: Is this really different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30126702/266304)?

Comment: It's same question, what I still didn't get an working query.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you calculate age in T-SQL

```
select case 
            when cast(getdate() as date) = cast(dateadd(year, (datediff(year, '1996-09-09', getdate())), '1996-09-09') as date)
                then dateDiff(yyyy,'1996-09-09',dateadd(year, 0, getdate()))
            else dateDiff(yyyy,'1996-09-09',dateadd(year, -1, getdate()))
        end as MemberAge
go
```